# How to Use append in recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am building a program and I need advice on this piece of code:

```
skyff([H1|Ta],L1,L2,):-
    skyff(Ta,L1,L22),
    append(H1,L2,L22).
```

To be more specific - what I want to accomplish is to append H1 to the List L2 and make a recursive call (skyff(Ta,L1,L22) ) where L22 is the result of appending H1 to L2. But I am unsure of if I am doing it right? - I didn't paste the code for the entire program since it is only this specific passage I am a bit uncertain of.

Maybe it should be the other way around:

```
skyff([H1|Ta],L1,L2,):-
        append(H1,L2,L22),
        skyff(Ta,L1,L22).
```

Comment: Is `H1` supposed to be a list, or is it just an element? In other words, do you want the new list, `L22` to be a list where `H1` is the first element and `L2` is the rest of the list? If so, then you would write it as `append([H1], L2, L22)` since `append/3` operates on lists normally, or even more succinct: `[H1|L2] = L22` (you don't need `append/3`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lurker comments are always on point and instructive, let's recap it

```
skyff([H1|Ta],L1,L2):-
        skyff(Ta,L1,[H1|L2]).
```

now, there is no more space for doubt...